# Calculating the time complexity of this specific code

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, time-complexity

Im trying to figure out the time complexity of the following code. `lst_of_lsts` contains `m` lists whose lengths are at most `n`.

This is what I think: all runs in `O(m*n)`, minimum = `O(m*n)`, remove = `O(m*n)`.

Overall `O(m*n)*O(m*n)` = `O(m^2*n^2)`

Am I right?

```
 def multi_merge_v1(lst_of_lsts): 
      all = [e for lst in lst_of_lsts for e in lst] 
      merged = [] 
      while all != []: 
          minimum = min(all) 
          merged += [minimum] 
          all.remove(minimum) 
      return merged
```

Comment: Isn't this code review?

Answer (score 1):

```
def multi_merge_v1(lst_of_lsts): # M lists of N
  all = [e for lst in lst_of_lsts for e in lst]
  # this is messy. Enumerate all N*M list items --> O(nm)

  merged = [] # O(1)
  while all != []: # n*m items initially, decreases in size by 1 each iteration.
    minimum = min(all) # O(|all|).
    # |all| diminishes linearly from (nm) items, so this is O(nm).
    # can re-use work here. Should use a sorted data structure or heap

    merged += [minimum] # O(1) amortized due to table doubling
    all.remove(minimum) # O(|all|)
  return merged # O(1)
```

The overall complexity appears to be O(nm + nm*nm + 1) = O(n^2m^2+1). Yikes.